# Insert from multiple tables, multiple rows

Tags: sql, oracle

I have been trying to solve my problem but could not find the answer.
Oracle db.

I have table *context* with looks like:

```
| contextId | customer |
 ----------------------
|         1 | John     |
|         2 | David    |
```

I have another table *setting*:

```
| contextId | settingName | settingValue |
 ----------------------------------------
|         1 | Happiness   |            6 |
|         1 | Sadness     |            3 |
```

What I would like is to insert David in *setting*, while copying the *settingName* and *settingValue* of John (contextId = 1).

Result should look like:

```
| contextId | settingName | settingValue |
 ----------------------------------------
|         1 | Happiness   |            6 |
|         1 | Sadness     |            3 |
|         2 | Happiness   |            6 |
|         2 | Sadness     |            3 |
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your requirement is to use the customer names 'David' and 'John', then you need a join:

```
INSERT INTO SETTING (CONTEXTID, SETTINGNAME, SETTINGVALUE)
  SELECT 
    (SELECT CONTEXTID FROM CONTEXT WHERE CUSTOMER = 'David'),
    s.SETTINGNAME,
    s.SETTINGVALUE
  FROM CONTEXT AS c INNER JOIN SETTING AS s 
  ON s.CONTEXTID = c.CONTEXTID
  WHERE c.CUSTOMER = 'John'
```

Comment: This is actually what I needed because context id is different depending on the environments this query is run (but the values are the same). That's why I mark this answer as accepted. But the answer of Chaitanya Kotha is also good.

Comment: Note that I had to remove 'AS' from the query for it to work though.

Answer (score 4):

```
INSERT INTO SETTING
  SELECT (SELECT CONTEXTID FROM CONTEXT WHERE CUSTOMER = 'DAVID'),
         SETTINGNAME,
         SETTINGVALUE
    FROM SETTING
   WHERE CONTEXTID = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Declared a separate variable to hold the `contextId` of `customer - David`. And inserting the multiple values available in `setting` table for `customer - David`.

```
DECLARE
  l_contextId context.contextId%TYPE;
BEGIN

  SELECT
    contextId
  INTO
    l_contextId
  FROM
    context
  WHERE
    customer = 'David';

END; 


INSERT INTO setting
(contextId, settingName, settingValue)
SELECT l_contextId, settingName, settingValue
FROM setting
WHERE contextId = 1
```